# Float and same margin

Tags: html, css

I've this situation as a figure
[image]

but I want margin-left and margin-right at the 3 boxes (33%).
But:
- if I apply margin-left:10px..threre is this situation
[image]

I want same margin to left of first boxe,between the boxes and to right of last boxe.

How to do?

**My Code :**

***PHP***

```
 <?php 
   $my_archives=wp_get_archives(array(
  'type'=>'yearly', 
   'format' => 'custom',
   'before' => '<span class="archivio-anno-list">hello<br>',
   'after' => '<br></span>',
   'show_post_count'=>true, 
   'limit'=>20, 
   'post_type'=>'issue_number', 
 ));

 print_r($my_archives); 

?>
```

***css***

```
.archivio-anno-list {

   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Use that element has a wrapper and have another one inside and set some padding on it.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: you have to show us what did you achieve, show us your code

Comment: apply margin in % and targer last child , it will work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `margin` go for `padding` and then place your content inside these `column` classes.
This layout is followed by **Bootstrap Framework** as well.
the value of `5px` contributes to a gutter of `10px` when combined.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flexBox as said in another answer, but if you want to use float:left , you need to calculate your width

set left-right margin of 5px to the boxes so in total, between the boxes, there's a 10px space

then the `width` of each `box` is `33.33%` ( 100%/3 ) - `10px`  ( the 5 left margin + 5 right margin )

now there is a problem because first box has only 5px on the left, and the right box has only 5px on the right, you can change this by add `padding:0 5px` to the `.wrapper`

as i don't know your HTML structure , i'm just guessing here. SEE SNIPPET below

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 5px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">

  </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>
  <div class="box">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find the solution, thanks to all!

my css code

```
.archivio-anno-list {float:left;margin-left:1%;width:32%;}
```

Comment: i suggest you don't use that if you want your site to be aligned perfectly ( for eg have 10px margins to all elements ) . use ` width: calc(33.33% - 10px);` as in the solution i provided you

Answer (score 1):

> The `%` approach as mentioned in my comments:

**Using % in margin and width this is too easy :)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background:yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left:1%;
  
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if he wants to have `10px` margins ? so he can align his site perfectly and have consistent margins ? `1%` changes

Comment: @Mihai then calc() wil help as explained in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .box  {
        float: left;
      width: 32%;
      text-align: center;
       margin-right:1%;
      background:blue;  
    }

    .box:nth-child(3n+2) {
      margin-right: 0%;
    }
```

Comment: Using selector nth-child(3n+2)